# Tables with dynamic names as fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains a field that when we add a letter to it it becomes a table name, so far i can only fetch all from the first table and then do each table_name at once. So i'm looking for a way to all of the above in one query.

Queries

```
select table_name from main
select date,data from X$table_name order by date desc limit 1
```

main

```
table_name      name 
000001          X1
000002          X2
000003          X3
000004          X4
000005          X5
```

Table X000001

```
id  date        data
5   2016-12-05  data_02_05
4   2016-12-04  data_02_04
3   2016-12-03  data_02_03
2   2016-12-02  data_02_02
1   2016-12-01  data_02_01
```

Table X000002

```
id  date        data
5   2016-12-05  data_02_05
4   2016-12-04  data_02_04
3   2016-12-03  data_02_03
2   2016-12-02  data_02_02
1   2016-12-01  data_02_01
```

Expected result

```
table_name      date            data
000001          2016-12-05      data_01_05
000002          2016-12-05      data_02_05
000003          2016-12-05      data_03_05
000004          2016-12-05      data_04_05
000005          2016-12-05      data_05_05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a dynamic query or prepared statement for that purpose.

```
declare @tab_name varchar(100);
set @tab_name := (select table_name from main);
SET @t1 := CONCAT("select `date`,data from X",@tab_name,"  order by `date` desc limit 1");
 PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
 EXECUTE stmt3;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
```

Comment: Does this work on mysql? it gave an error on declare so changed it to select @table_name but it doesn't show anything..

Comment: @0x58, yes it does but you will have wrap it in a `begin..end` block inside a stored procedure

Comment: I managed to do what you said but still get this error **CALL failed: (1242) Subquery returns more than 1 row** for line **select @tab_name := (select table_name from main);** it only works when i add limit 1

Comment: @0x58, shouldn't it be? it should be since you are selecting that column value and so all will be returned. Moreover, it's a separate question and so post it separately. explaining what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have written a class for MySQL PS... https://github.com/DennisWeidmann/SQLContentProvider